Automapper not mapping null value
I'm trying to map a nullable property, but the automapper indicates an error in this mapping.
Property: HomeTown
Source: Person.NaturalPerson.HomeTown
Destination: PersonDTO.NaturalPersonDTO.HomeTown
When the property is null in the source, the following error occurs:
Mapping types:
Person -> PersonDTO
LogSistemas.Domynus.Application.Core.Entities.Person.Person -> LogSistemas.Domynus.Application.Core.Dto.Person.PersonDTO

Type Map configuration:
Person -> PersonDTO
LogSistemas.Domynus.Application.Core.Entities.Person.Person -> LogSistemas.Domynus.Application.Core.Dto.Person.PersonDTO

Destination Member:
NaturalPerson

 ---> AutoMapper.AutoMapperMappingException: Error mapping types.

Mapping types:
NaturalPerson -> NaturalPersonDTO
LogSistemas.Domynus.Application.Core.Entities.Person.NaturalPerson -> LogSistemas.Domynus.Application.Core.Dto.Person.NaturalPersonDTO

Type Map configuration:
NaturalPerson -> NaturalPersonDTO
LogSistemas.Domynus.Application.Core.Entities.Person.NaturalPerson -> LogSistemas.Domynus.Application.Core.Dto.Person.NaturalPersonDTO

Destination Member:
HomeTown

 ---> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Classes
public class NaturalPerson
{
    public NaturalPerson()
    {
        HomeTown = new();
    }

    public City HomeTown { get; set; }
}

public class NaturalPersonDTO
{
    public NaturalPersonDTO()
    {
        HomeTown = new CityDTO();
    }

    public CityDTO HomeTown { get; set; }
}

Mapping config
    CreateMap<Entities.Person.Person, PersonDTO>();
    CreateMap<Entities.Person.NaturalPerson, NaturalPersonDTO>();
    CreateMap<City, CityDTO>()
        .ConvertUsing(x => new CityDTO
        {
            Id = x.Id,
            StateId = x.StateId,
            Name = x.Name,
            State = x.State.Abbreviation,
            Country = x.State.Country.Name
        });

As far as I know, automapper maps null without any problems. I couldn't figure this out.

The error complains about HomeTown, a CityDTO. You don't check whether x.State is null so x.State.Abbreviation will throw. Post the actual full exception text. You could avoid the error if you used x.State?.Abbreviation

That's just manual mapping. AM does the null checks for you, but you need to write a proper map, not a type converter.

Automapper try to map city of Hometown in NaturalPerson to DTO even if HomeTown is null?
Exception complete text is too long for post here

@LucianBargaoanu i see, that's clarified. Thanks.

You can't map your nullable property because your mapper profile specifically says to create new object CityDTO from City. So when City is null, then mapper can't perform what you told him.
You need to modify your mapping profile to something like this:
...
CreateMap<Entities.Person.NaturalPerson, NaturalPersonDTO>();
CreateMap<City, CityDTO>()
    .ForPath(dist => dist.State, op => op.MapFrom(src => src.State.Abbreviation))
    .ForPath(dist => dist.Country, op => op.MapFrom(src => src.State.Country.Name));


Automapper try to map city of Hometown in NaturalPerson to DTO even if HomeTown is null?

In your provided option you're making mandatory to create new CityDTO.

ok, i get it, thansk for helping!!
